# mongoDB user management (built in or own implementation)

Tags: mongodb, access-control

I started to evaluate mongoDB for a product catalogue.
Regarding user management and access control: When to use the mongoDB's built in user management and when build one on the application layer?

Let us say I have a product catalogue organised as a Tree. I want to define access rights on the nodes of the tree.

Access rights could the be inherited from the parent product group to all its products and articles.

Comment: [Why was my question closed as too broad?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6490/) There are too many situations where the use of either is valid for us to give an answer as the question is written. You have not given us an specifics about your requirements to even be able to start to help.

Comment: I have added the restriction that we have a structure organised as a tree and I want to define the rights on the nodes of the tree. The question is not that braod any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB itself can only define access privileges per collection, not per document. You likely want all the nodes in the same collection so you can query them properly (MongoDB can't query more than one collection in the same command). That means enforcing the access privilege on the database won't be sufficient. You will have to implement access control on the application server.

For further reading about permissions in MongoDB I recommend the [MongoDB User and Role Management Tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security-user-role-management/) as well as the [$redact aggregation stage](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact) which is primarily designed to filter documents based on application-defined permissions.

Comment: So you are basically suggesting having one user for the web application and then implement filtering in the application with the help of $redact?

Comment: @Matthias Yes, that's what I am suggesting.